# Stacking Multiple Initiator Classes

Tags: dnd-3.5e, tome-of-battle

If i'm playing with a Swordsage 13/Warblade 2/Master of Nine 5, what will my Initiator level be?

Is it one of these?:

1. **20** (12 SS + 2 WB + 5 Mo9);
2. **19** (12 SS + 1 (Half WB Progression) + 5 Mo9);
3. **13** with SS, **2** with WB and **5** Initiator levels to add as I please to either SS or WB?

Comment: It seems your problem is working out which of those options you are, so I've edited your question to actually ask that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Martial base classes each have their own separate initiator level, just as spellcasting classes have their own separate caster levels, psionic classes have their own separate manifester levels, and so on. Unlike those other cases, however, initiator level includes half your level in *other* classes – including other initiating classes.

> ### Initiator Level
>
> #### Multiclass Characters
>
> If you are a multiclass martial adept,
>   and you learn a new maneuver by attaining a new level in a
>   martial adept class, determine your initiator level by adding
>   together your level in that class + 1/2 your levels in all other
>   classes. Look up the result on the table below to determine
>   the highest-level maneuvers you can take. You still have to
>   meet a maneuver’s prerequisite to learn it.
>
> For example, **a 7th-level crusader/5th-level swordsage
>   has an initiator level of 9th for determining the highest-
>   level maneuvers he can take as a crusader.** As a result, he
>   can take 5th-level crusader maneuvers. **As a swordsage, his
>   initiator level is 8th, allowing him to take 4th-level sword-
>   sage maneuvers.**
>
> This process applies to all of a character’s levels, whether
>   they are in martial adept classes or other classes.
>
> Prestige classes work a little differently. In most cases, you
>   add the full prestige class level to your martial adept level to
>   determine your initiator level. See the prestige class descriptions in Chapter 5 for details.

<sup>(*Tome of Battle* pg. 39, **emphasis** mine)</sup>

Clearly, the Crusader 7/Swordsage 5 example is quite similar to your Swordsage 13/Warblade 2, so clearly at 15th level you had a swordsage IL of 14 (13 + ½×2) and a warblade IL of 8 (½×13 + 2).

As it says right there at the end, prestige classes are a little different, mostly in that “you add the full prestige class level to your martial adept level to determine your initiator level.” This means the five levels of master of the nine counts for both swordsage and warblade, for ILs of 19 and 13, respectively.

The mention in the prestige class section defines how learning maneuvers and getting more maneuvers readied works. It does not directly address initiator level, however.

> ## Prestige Classes
>
> ### Advancing Martial Progression
>
> #### Martial Adepts
>
> If you have levels in a martial adept standard class (crusader,
>   swordsage, or warblade), you retain the same method for
>   readying and recovering maneuvers that you previously
>   used. If you have levels in two or more martial adept standard
>   classes (for example, you are a multiclass swordsage/warblade), you must decide to which of your existing martial
>   adept classes **the new maneuvers known or maneuvers
>   readied** apply.

<sup>(*Tome of Battle* pg. 96, **emphasis** mine)</sup>

Note that you choose which existing class gets the new maneuvers known or readied, **not** the initiator level.

Master of the nine simply repeats what was said on page 39:

> You add your full master
>   of nine levels to your initiator level to determine your total
>   initiator level and your highest-level maneuvers known.

<sup>(*Tome of Battle* pg. 119)</sup>

Since *Tome of Battle* only ever says that you simply go ahead and add prestige class levels in full to initiator level, this has been interpreted, universally that I have seen, to simply do exactly that: add on to any and all initiator levels you have. Nothing in *Tome of Battle* ever says that you must choose which class to add prestige class levels to, as every spellcasting prestige class does.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Since it's default, and the swordsage example demonstrates it, I'm inclined not to.

Answer (score 4):

As an initiator, you have a different initiator level for each of your two classes. All other basic classes add 1/2 of their levels to your total initiator level. Master of 9 adds all of its levels to your total initiator level.

So, a Swordsage 13/ Warblade 2/ Master of Nine 5 has:

A Swordsage initiator Level of **19**: 13 Swordsage + 1(1/2 of 2) Warblade + 5 Mo9

A Warblade initiator Level of **13**: 2 Warblade + 6(1/2 of 13) Swordsage + 5 Mo9

Determining Initiator Level:

> If you are a multiclass martial adept... determine your initiator level by adding your level in that class +1/2 of your levels in all other classes.
>
> A 7th level Crusader/5th level Swordsage has an initiator Level of 9th for determining the highest level maneuvers he can take as a Crusader. As a Swordsage his initiator Level is 8.
>
> Prestige Classes work a little differently. For the most part, you add the full Prestige Class level to your martial Adept Level

(Tome of Battle, p. 39)

Comment: There is some text in the book that explicity says so? I'm in a RAW battle to check the IL of my character. My gaming group don't consider FAQs to be RAW or Official, though.